# Coordinates not being labelled in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, coordinates

I am working on a basemap by plotting GPS coordinates taken during a field survey onto a basemap in ArcMap.

I imported coordinates from Excel in CSV format and the points have been plotted correctly.

I want to label the points with the area name. The data I imported from Excel includes the names of the area and coordinates but when I go in layer properties and select label, the points are not being labelled.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table? How did you import the table from excel?

Comment: I imported the table in csv format from excel

Comment: I know, but how?

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual behavior.

But you can achieve the desired objectives by exporting the imported table plotted in ArcMap as a shapefile or an FC and try labeling.

Comment: Thanku will try this